# Application define or object define error while copying cells from one work sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I am trying to copy and paste cells A:B and cells defined in "CELL H7" of my current work book from one workbook to another.

Cell H7 Is O:O

However I keep having object define error in my current set up.

Please kindly advise what mistake i have made and how should i rectify this mistake.

```
Sub TransferData()
'transfer stuff from workbook 1 to workbook 2

    Dim strPath1 As Range
    Dim strPath2 As Range
    Dim wbkWorkbook1 As Workbook
    Dim wbkWorkbook2 As Workbook
    Dim Copypath As Range

    'define paths and filenames
    Set strPath1 = Range("G13")
    Set strPath2 = Range("G14")
    Set Copypath = Range("H7")
    'open files
    Set wbkWorkbook1 = Workbooks.Open(strPath1)
    Set wbkWorkbook2 = Workbooks.Open(strPath2)

    'copy the values across
    wbkWorkbook2.Worksheets(1).Range("A:B").Value = _
        wbkWorkbook1.Worksheets(1).Range("A:B").Value

    wbkWorkbook2.Worksheets(1).Range(Copypath).Value = _
        wbkWorkbook1.Worksheets(1).Range("C:C").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: `Copypath` is `H7` and has a different size than `A:B`. So the range `A:B` (2 full columns) just cannot fit in `H7`. • If you copy like `Range(…).Value = Range(…).Value` both ranges need to be exactly the same size.

Comment: Hello, thanks alot for the comment, in  "H7"  I have indicated "O:O", which is one full column. apologies i have actually had a typo, the new column that O:O is supposed to copy in is C:C

Comment: What is the value in cell H7?

Comment: @jivko Value in H7 is O:O

Comment: Just tested with O:O and it runs without an error. Are you sure it's O:O and not "O:O"?

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify in which sheet VBA shoud look for H7 `Set Copypath = Range("H7")`. Here VBA guesses which sheet you mean and probably it is looking in the wrong sheet. Specify a sheet for that (and the other) ranges!.

Excel does not know in which sheet to look for the ranges.

```
Set strPath1 = Range("G13") 
Set strPath2 = Range("G14")
Set Copypath = Range("H7")
```

Specify like

```
Set strPath1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName").Range("G13") 
'same for the other ranges …
```

Answer (score -2):

Use a With ... End With block so you can resize the target range to accept the dimensions of the source.

```
with wbkWorkbook2.Worksheets(1).Range(Copypath)
    wbkWorkbook1.Worksheets(1).Range("C1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
end with
```